# SpringBoot + Resilience4j Circuit Breaker - Actuator details are not updated

Tags: java, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am using Java 17, Spring boot 2.6.3, CXF 3.4.5 and REDIS.

When I was using CircuitBreaker annotation, requests was not intercepted upon Soap service was unavailable. So I needed to decorate requests.

```
try {
  Function<GetDetailsRequest, GetDetailsResponse> decorated = CircuitBreaker
   .decorateFunction(cb, service::getDetails);
  decorated.apply(request);
} catch (CallNotPermittedException e) {
  redisLockService.unlock(request);
  throw CallNotPermittedException.createCallNotPermittedException(cb);
} catch (Exception e) {
  redisLockService.unlock(request);
  throw new ExternalTechnicalException("Problem with connection to service - getDetails");
}
```

This works fine, however, details in /actuator/health/circuitBreakers are not updated when CallNotPermittedException is thrown.

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "service": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "failureRate": "-1.0%",
        "failureRateThreshold": "50.0%",
        "slowCallRate": "-1.0%",
        "slowCallRateThreshold": "100.0%",
        "bufferedCalls": 0,
        "slowCalls": 0,
        "slowFailedCalls": 0,
        "failedCalls": 0,
        "notPermittedCalls": 0,
        "state": "CLOSED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added configuration like in examples from the following link, but this didnt resolve the problem. https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/micrometer#circuitbreaker-metrics

Do I need some additional configuration which I dont know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: In a way yeah. I have noticed that CB doesn't work with CXF. You can easily omit the problem adding public method with @CircuitBreaker annotation and within the method using private method with calling to the SOAP Service. You can call it wrapper method ;)